# How to populate a column based on cell data matching Items in list

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table in excel like the example below:

| Box Size | Header | Header | Header | Header | Header | Header | Header | Header | Header | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Full |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | Apples |
| Full |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | Oranges |
| Half |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | Grapes |
| Half |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | Lemons |

Box size is in column A, Description is in column K.
The box size is automatically "Full" for all rows and I must change them to say "Half" manually.
I have a list of items on Sheet2 called "HalfBox" like the example below:

| Half Items |
| --- |
| Grapes |
| Lemons |

I am trying to find a macro that will compare the descriptions in column K with the list in Sheet2.  If a match is found I would like to automatically change the value in the A cell to say "Half".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1:

- Load source data into `arrData1`, load items list into `arrData2`
- Use `StrComp` to compare the description and items (case-insensitive)
- If `Half Items` is a large list, loading it into a `Dictionary` object can improve the efficiency of comparation

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [StrComp function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/strcomp-function?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vblr6.chm1009035)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub Demo()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim  arrData2, rngData1 As Range, rngData2 As Range
    Const DES_COL = 11
    Set rngData1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Set rngData2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").CurrentRegion
    arrData1 = rngData1.Value
    arrData2 = rngData2.Value
    For i = LBound(arrData1) + 1 To UBound(arrData1)
        For j = LBound(arrData2) + 1 To UBound(arrData2)
            If StrComp(arrData1(i, DES_COL), arrData2(j, 1), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                arrData1(i, 1) = "Half"
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    rngData1.Value = arrData1
End Sub
```

---

Option 2:

- Apply formulas on col A, eg. the formula on Sheet1 A2

```
=IF(COUNTIF(Sheet2!A:A,Sheet1!K2)>0,"Half","Full")
```

Comment: Option 1 worked great!  FYI all the solutions you have given me in the past few months are part of one giant macro that completely automates all the operations of this workbook.  Huge thanks for all the help!  There is one operation outstanding that I posted in another question today titled: "Activate auto-filter for columns D-J based on active checkbox in excel"

Comment: I'll look into it shortly.

Comment: I have found a case where Option 1 did not work.  There is a cell that has the "Grapes" partial string included with other text.  Like "Grapes In Bundle".  This did not get the "Half" modification while the cell below it that only contains "Grapes" did.  This is tricky not being able to divulge any information about the actual workbook due to strict corporate policies but I think this example explains it well enough.

Comment: Replace StrComp with InStr. You can find sample code in previous posts.